Verification of a Closed-Form Expression for a Multivariable Integral Involving Exponentials and Bessel Functions
Consider the complex parameters $\mathbf{s}=(s_1,s_2,...,s_n)\in \Bbb C^n$ and real parameters $\mathbf{t}=(t_1,t_2,...,t_n)\in\Bbb R^n$ and take the function $I(\mathbf{s},\mathbf{t})$ defined by the $n$-dimensional integral:
$$
I(\mathbf{s},\mathbf{t}) = \int_{[0,1]^n} \left( \prod_{i=1}^n x_i^{s_i - 1} \right) \exp\left( \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{t_i}{\ln x_i} \right) \, d\mathbf{x}
.$$
Based on computations I've done I think that:
$$I(\mathbf{s},\mathbf{t})= 2\sqrt{\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n t_i}{\prod_{i=1}^n s_i }}K_1\bigg( 
2\sqrt{\bigg(\sum_{i=1}^n t_i\bigg)\bigg( \prod_{i=1}^n s_i} \bigg) \bigg) $$
where $K_1$ is the modified Bessel function of the second kind.

Can this closed form be verified?


No work shown, so there’s that. Did you introduce the change of variable $u_i := -\ln x_i$?

Yes @ruralreader

I did verify $n=1$ works with my proposed form, using computer software and Mellin transform techniques
